# What metadata table will give the correct number of attributes after altering an object type in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

can somebody help me with this.

I created an object type with 2 attributes:

```
Create or replace type type_t1 as object
(
 Col_1 number(5),
 Col_2 number(3));
```

Then I altered it using command:

```
Alter type type_t1 add attribute ( col3 number(2)) cascade
```

It executed successfully.

Now when I check in metadata table dba_type_attrs for my type, the count gives only 2 , while it should be 3.

```
Select count(1) from dba_type_attrs where type_name='type_t1';
```

Can somebody suggest why the metadata table is not giving correct number of attributes after altering the object type. Is there anything else to be done or any other metadata table is there.

Comment: Maybe you have two types: `type_t1` and `TYPE_T1` and your question doesn't reveal all your work?

Answer (score 0):

That's just not correct. Besides, info you posted is wrong - you created type `type_t1` which is then stored in UPPERCASE into data dictionary, while your `select` references it with lower case so that query won't return anything.

Demo:

```
SQL> create or replace type type_t1 as object ( col_1 number(5), col_2 number(3));
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> select type_name, attr_name from user_type_attrs;

TYPE_NAME                      ATTR_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TYPE_T1                        COL_1
TYPE_T1                        COL_2

SQL> alter type type_t1 add attribute ( col3 number(2)) cascade;

Type altered.

SQL> select type_name, attr_name from user_type_attrs;

TYPE_NAME                      ATTR_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TYPE_T1                        COL_1
TYPE_T1                        COL_2
TYPE_T1                        COL3

SQL> select count(1) from user_type_attrs where type_name='TYPE_T1';

  COUNT(1)
----------
         3

SQL>
```

---

I suggest you do the same: copy/paste your SQL*Plus session which illustrates the problem (if it exists at all).

---

**[EDIT]** P.S. Forgot to mention: you're querying `DBA_TYPE_ATTRS`; don't forget to include **owner** into query as more than just one user can have the same type name:

```
SQL> select owner, type_name, attr_name from dba_type_attrs where type_name = 'TYPE_T1';

OWNER                          TYPE_NAME                      ATTR_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
SCOTT                          TYPE_T1                        COL3
SCOTT                          TYPE_T1                        COL_1
SCOTT                          TYPE_T1                        COL_2

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will retry it!